# Clipping convex polygon produces convex polygon - but why?

Tags: geometry, proof-writing, euclidean-geometry

It's quite obvious to me that if I clip any convex polygon with a half-space, the resulting polygon will be convex. I explain it to myself by "a straight line can't introduce concavity", but is there a proper, mathematical proof to it?

I have used this property extensively in my thesis (computer science, not mathematics), but realized now I can't come up with any sound argument why my assumption holds. Proving it is out of scope of my work, but I would like to understand the proof myself. Points to any reading/papers that I could cite are also very welcome :)

Comment: A convex polygon is itself the intersection of half spaces. Adding one does not change matters. Likewise for the intersection of two convex polygons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The convex polygon and half-space are both convex sets, and the result of clipping the polygon by the half-space is merely their intersection, which will be convex from [this result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1016304/proof-that-the-intersection-of-any-finite-number-of-convex-sets-is-a-convex-set). So in case the intersection forms a polygon, it will be a convex one.

Comment: thank you! Is it a well known fact that I can just state, or would you have any reference to cite?

Comment: @elena This is an elementary result in the study of convex sets, so I don't think citation would be necessary.

Comment: @elena Try to prove it yourself from the definition of convexity: if $A$ and $B$ are convex sets, this means for any $p,q \in A$ the segment $[p,q]$ also lies in $A$, and similarly for $B$. Now, if $p,q \in A\cap B$, then $p,q \in A$ **and** $p,q \in B$, so...

Comment: @ShubhamJohri "So in case the intersection forms a polygon, it will be convex." - this is a bit misleading, "it" may be understood to refer to either "the intersection" or "a polygon". May I suggest rewriting the last part as "it will be a convex one"?

Comment: @lisyarus fixed.

Comment: @lisyarus I'm afraid I'm lacking some set theory knowledge. $p,q \in A \cap B$ is a subset of $A$ as well as $B$. Apparently that makes it convex, but I'm only guessing, it is not obvious for me.

Comment: @elena You need to show $A\cap B$ is convex if $A,B$ are convex. Assume two points $p,q\in A\cap B$. Then since $A\cap B\subseteq A,p,q\in A$. Using the convexity of $A$, you get that the entire line joining $p,q$ lies in $A$. Similarly $p,q\in B$ and the said line also belongs to $B$. Hence the said line belongs to $A\cap B$ for every $p,q\in A\cap B$, giving that $A\cap B$ is convex.

Comment: For the general case, see the link I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri I've been reading over it, and could kinda understand, but not really. Now since you've put it into words, it became really clear. "the line between $p$ and $q$" is what I was missing, I was thinking only in terms of points. Thank you both, ShubhamJohri for the answers and lisyarus for forcing me to think harder.